# Incrementing a variable in as3 to give different results

Tags: actionscript-3

I need a variable to increment a value in each click of the mouse clicks in the end according to the final results. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m_myValue:int = 0;
this.stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this._onClick );

private function _onClick( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    this.m_myValue++;
}
```

bam

Answer (score 0):

apply the values ​​of variables to a dynamic text box in flash as3??